# Bernoulli's principle: Why an increase in the section area in a hose makes the pressure increase?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, continuum-mechanics, fluid-statics, bernoulli-equation

I'm having trouble understanding Bernoulli's principle, in particular, why an increase in the section area of a hose increases the pressure?

All  the answers I read say: " In order for the energy to be conserved" or "when the tube is compressed, the fluid **has** to speed up so that the same amount of the fluid gets out of the tube in the same interval of time (continuity law)".

I'm not looking for the **finality** : energy conservation. I'm trying to understand the **mechanism**, what happens at the molecular level?

Comment: At he molecular level number of particles coliding with the unit area of the surface decreases as the area increases.

Comment: So far none of the answers below have dealt with your original misconception.  According to Bernoulli's principle, the pressure _increases_  in the section of hose with the larger cross section.

Comment: I fixed the OP's mistake (probably just a typo) to eliminate some of the confusion.

Comment: Corrected the title

Comment: Hello! I think I've been asking the wrong question. I wanted to know what happens at the "transition region" and Bernoulli's law describes what happens  when the fluid is already flowing. Also the principle is applied in continuum mechanics where things are not explained at the molecular level.

Comment: However, Pascal's equation of "force multiplication" may answer the question. What do you think?

Comment: No. What you are talking is a principle of *hydrostatics*, which has nothing to do with your question, I think; even though by now, with your last comments, I admit that I have no idea what it really is you are after. What "transition region"? Is this about unsteady flow now?

Comment: I meant the region where the section area changes.

Comment: The transition region can be broken into small segments and each of them treated as "non-transitioning regions" as long as the segments are larger than the thermalization scale.

So now you will say you want to go to shorter length scales and then we are back to the non-thermodynamic regime where Bernoulli's principle is simply not valid. Basically you are trying to use an equation beyond its range of validity.

Comment: What you want to do is understand how the walls force the molecules on squeezing and how the effect gets transmitted to the bulk and spreads out (or rather in) to reach equilibria. Good luck with that! But it is beyond Bernoulli's principle which is a coarse grained result.

Answer (score 6):

> I'm trying to understand the **mechanism**, what happens at the molecular level?

Bernoulli's Principle belongs to *continuum mechanics*, so it's not well suited to make pronouncements about action at the molecular level (but I'll get back to that further down).

Between two points on the same flowline [Bernoulli states](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pber.html):

$$P_1+\frac12 \rho v_1^2+\rho gz_1=P_2+\frac12 \rho v_2^2+\rho gz_2$$

The case below is for an inviscid, incompressible fluid, with no potential energy changes ($z=\mathrm{constant}$) and regularly shaped conduits (the cross sections $A_1$ and $A_2$ are well defined):

[image: Bernoulli equation]

Then:

$$P_1+\frac12 \rho v_1^2=P_2+\frac12 \rho v_2^2$$

The relationship between the flow speeds is given by incompressible continuity:

$Q_v=A_1v_1=A_2v_2=\mathrm{constant}\implies v_2=\frac{A_1}{A_2}v_1$

So that:

$P_2=P_1+\frac12 \rho (v_1^2-v_2^2)$

$P_2=P_1+\frac12 \rho \Big(1-\frac{A_1^2}{A_2^2}\Big)v_1^2$

Thus: $\boxed{A_2>A_1\implies v_2<v_1\implies P_2>P_1}$

So what you call the 'mechanism' is entirely due to satisfying the continuity requirement. **Counter-intuitively perhaps**, here a decrease in flow speed $v$ results in an increase in pressure $P$.

**At the molecular level**, lower bulk fluid pressure is caused by increased average distances between molecules, as these increases decrease Coulombic repulsions between the electron clouds that make up the fluid's molecules. This results in lower numbers of collisions with the counduit's wall and thus lower pressure.

Comment: I was trying to think of a satisfying way to explain it closer to a molecular level and kept ending up at the unsatisfying solution you gave in your last paragraph.  Your point on continuity is great and was what I was struggling to realize.  Continuity laws by definition aren't applicable to systems close to the molecular level.

Comment: @Gert you show that the pressure increases with increasing cross-sectional area, but the OP begins with the opposite assumption. Also, the "molecular level" explanation seems to contradict the finding in the derivation by explaining lower pressure.

Comment: @D.Ennis: that's because the OP's assertion was wrong, see e.g. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pber.html . Also, the molecular level explanation of pressure stands alone from Bernoulli (which is continuum mechanics).

Comment: @Gert, Yes, I know that his assertion was incorrect, as I expressed in my comment following his question.  I just found it remarkable that no one told him so explicitly in their answers.    Also, are you saying that the molecular level explanation is entitled to contradict Bernoulli's principle?

Comment: @D.Ennis how does it contradict it?

Comment: @D.Ennis: as JMac points out: whether pressure is increased or decreased has nothing to do with *how pressure arises*. That's the point to my second point. And shows again one *must* respect the strength and limitations of continuum mechanics: it ain't QM!

Comment: @Gert To expand on that a little; besides the basic continuity equations; the only thing about it I really remember is the blurb in my textbook that explicitly stated that these methods were only valid on a scale large enough to ignore molecular interactions.  They even provided some quick calculation to check.

Comment: Yes, all CM is macroscopic in character.

Comment: By definition it has to be.

Comment: @JMac Here's the contradiction.  Bernoulli's principle predicts that the fluid pressure will be greater in the larger sections.  And the prediction is confirmed when you stick a pressure gauge in there and find that the pressure really is higher there than in the smaller sections.  And Gert's answer agrees.  But then the molecular level discussion goes on to explain why the pressure is __lower__.

Comment: @D.Ennis: *"But then the molecular level discussion goes on to explain why the pressure is lower"* Actually, I do nothing of the sort. I simply (very simply, in fact) explain what lower pressure means ot the molecular level. As I cannot repeat enough, Bernoulli makes **no pronouncements** about how at the micro level pressure in conduits works. That's not something that CM concerns itself with. The OP's question was in that respect a little 'awkward' (but valid nonetheless).

Comment: Then you may want to edit the answer. Stylistically, there is no transition between those two paragraphs to indicate that the second one is not a further elaboration of the first one. Meanwhile, the use of the bolded phrases in both paragraphs reinforces the impression that you are still talking about the large section, and finally the context--the OP asking about the large section--favors misinterpretation.

Comment: @Gert, I think this is a great answer. And it clears my mind about what happens basicly on the molecular level. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your quest for a "mechanism" is almost sure to fail as you are talking about how an Avogadro number of molecules interact with each other. That is precisely why macroscopic quantities like energy and density (in the continuity equation) are used.

However, we can still try to get some intuition more than just saying energy is conserved (I will still use it though) for the case of ideal gas.

The point is pressure come from force per unit area from random motion of molecules. When the fluid **has to** (continuity equation) pass through a narrow tube, it has to increase its velocity in a certain direction (i.e. the tube direction) and then since energy **has to** be conserved, assuming 'thermalization' happens at time scales much faster than it takes to pass through the tube, the fraction of energy available for 'random' kinetic energy and thus pressure, is less.

If you prefer mathematical expressions, for $N \gg 1$ molecules of unit mass, the total energy (ignoring potential energies from bound states and walls of container) is

$$
2 E = \sum_{i=1}^N \vec v_i.\vec v_i = \sum_{i=1}^N (\vec v_i- \vec v_0  + \vec v_0 ).(\vec v_i- \vec v_0  + \vec v_0 ) \\
=\sum_{i=1}^N (\vec v_i- \vec v_0).(\vec v_i- \vec v_0) + N~\vec v_0. \vec v_0
$$
where $\vec v_0 = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \vec v_i$ is the mean velocity of the $N$ molecules and the cross terms vanishes in the limit $N \to \infty$ because the 'random flucatuations' about the mean are isotropic. The first part contributes to pressure and the second is the velocity through the tube. You can clearly see the effect you mentioned.

Comment: My answer should be taken with a grain of salt as I use ideal gas kind of arguments and yet take it to be in-compressible. However, I think as a hand-wavey argument it does 'explain' how lower preassure comes from a lack of equi-partition of energy.

Answer (score -1):

When The Section Area Increases,the Fluid Molecules Are Spread Widely Thus The Collissions Per Unit Area Decreases .This Makes The Corresponding Exerted Pressure Decrease.

Comment: the density of the fluid remains, it is not in number of collisions/area